# Does MySQL table size matters when doing JOINs?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to design a high-performance database for tracking clicks and then displaying analytics of these clicks.

I expect at least 10M clicks to be coming in per 2 weeks time.

There are a few variables (each of them would need a unique column) that I'll allow people to use when using the click tracking - but I don't want to limit them to a number of these variables to 5 or so. That's why I thought about creating Table B where I can store these variables for each click.

However each click might have like 5-15+ of these variables depending on how many are they using. If I store them in a separate table that will multiple the 10M/2 weeks by the variables that the user might use.

In order to display analytics for the variables, I'll need to JOIN the tables.

Looking at both writing and most importantly reading performance, is there any difference if I JOIN a 100M rows table to a:

- 500 rows table OR to a 100M rows table?

Anyone recommends denormalizing it, like having 20 columns and store NULL vaules if they're not in use?

Comment: You're thinking about the database completely wrong. It just doesn't work like that. It's not like you have a huge bucket that you put on top of another huge bucket. Rather, you take a glass of water from each bucket and connect those. This is where indexes and data structures come into play. If you JOIN two tables but have other conditions (`WHERE x = y AND z = k`) then you're joining two reduced data sets. Yes, table size WILL matter, but not in the way you think.

Comment: @Mjh A WHERE condition would not impact a JOIN timing at all. A WHERE is executed after the JOIN is executed, meaning a JOIN would occur in full even if you had a WHERE where nothing matched.

Comment: @yanman1234 your answer states that optimizer chooses the strategy. That's what I wanted to highlight. The answer is not black and white. Much like it's not possible to design the best performing database ever running on unknown hardware, which is always the constraining factor.

Comment: @Mjh The question is not how to design the best database, it is asking a simple question about JOINs. Your comment alluded to a filtering mechanism impacting JOIN timing which I corrected to avoid false information being passed around. Also in your comment you fail to mention anything about the optimizer you were trying to highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**is there any difference if I JOIN a 100M rows table to a...**

Yes there is. A JOIN's performance matters solely on how long it takes to find matching rows based on your ON condition. This means increasing row size of a joined table will increase the JOIN time, since there's more rows to sift through for matches. In general, a JOIN can be thought of as taking A*B time, where A is the number of rows in the first table and B is the number of rows in the second. This is a very broad statement as there are many optimization strategies the optimizer may take to change this value, but this can be thought of as a general rule.

To increase a JOIN's efficiency, for reads specifically, you should look into [indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html). Indexing allows you to mark a column that the optimizer should *index*, or keep a running track of to allow quicker evaluation of the values. This increases any write operation since the data needs to modify an encompassing data structure, usually a B-Tree, but decreases the time read operations since the data is presorted in this data structure allowing for quick look ups.

**Anyone recommends denormalizing it, like having 20 columns and store NULL vaules if they're not in use?**

There's a lot of factors that would go into saying yes or no here. Mainly, would storage space be an issue and how likely is duplicate data to appear. If the answers are that storage space is not an issue and duplicates are not likely to appear, then one large table may be the right decision. If you have limited storage space, then storing the excess nulls may not be smart. If you have many duplicate values, then one large table may be more inefficient than a JOIN.

Another factor to consider when denormalizing is if another table would ever want to access values from just one of the previous two tables. If yes, then the JOIN to obtain these values after denormalizing would be more inefficient than having the two tables separate. This question is really something you need to handle yourself when designing the database and seeing how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

First: There is a huge difference between joining 10m to 500 or 10m to 10m entries!

But using a propper index and structured table design will make this manageable for your goals I think. (at least depending on the hardware used to run the application)

I would totally NOT recommend to use denormalized tables, cause adding more than your 20 values will be a mess once you have 20m entries in your table. So even if there are some good reasons which might stand for using denormalized tables (performance, tablespace,..) this is a bad idea for further changes - but in the end your decison ;)